# Uncaught TypeError: Data[option] is not a function error occurred when using .datepicker('getDate')

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-datepicker

I've encountered an error `data[option] is not a function` whenever i tried to use `.datepicker('getDate')`.

I used this code to initialize the datepicker

```
<h4>Transaction Date:</h4>
        From:
        <input id="startDate" width="276" />
        To:
        <input id="endDate" width="276" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#startDate').datepicker();
        $('#endDate').datepicker();
</script>
```

But when I used this code to try to get the value of the set date on the datepicker.

```
alert($('#endDate').datepicker('getDate'));
```

I received an error `data[option] is not a function` eventhough i already have a bootstrap-datepicker.js on my scripts and also I've checked my bootstrap-datepicker.js it also have the function for `getDate` so now I'm having a hard time on determining what is really the problem.

Here are the included Scripts:

```
bootstrap-datepicker.js
bootstrap.js
jquery-3.4.1.js
respond.js
```

Comment: Have you checked your devtools console window to see if it is displaying any errors?

Comment: Yes I've already check my devtools console and it shows the error `Uncaught TypeError: data[option] is not a function`

Comment: I do not see `uiLibrary` as a valid option for bootstrap datepicker in their [documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html) but it is available for [Gijgo](https://gijgo.com/datepicker/configuration) If you are planning to use that, you will have to import relative js file gijgo.min.js

Comment: Yes I've used Gijgo here. But what I wanted to know is how can I solve my problem? Is there any conflict on Gijgo and the script that i wanted to run?

Comment: If you have `gijgo.min.js` in your scripts, you should remove `bootstrap-datepicker.js` from scripts. It will result in conflicts because both use `.datepicker()` to initialize the date picker

Comment: I've removed the `gijgo` instead of removing the `bootstrap-datepicker.js` because my datepicker doesn't work when i remove the `bootstrap-datepicker.js`. But it still produces the same error.

Comment: If you are removing `gijgo`, then  you cannot use `uiLibrary`. Change your code to only `$('#startDate').datepicker()` & `$('#endDate').datepicker()`

Comment: Thank you I've already change it and the datepicker works properly but still the same error occurs when I try to execute `alert($('#endDate').datepicker('getDate'));`

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show included `<scripts>`

Comment: I've already edited my question you can check it now.

Comment: jquery-3.4.1.js should be the first script followed by bootstrap.js. Then, you don't need bootstrap-datepicker.js since you are already including bootstrap-datepicker.min.js. Also remove respond.js since you already have respond.min.js.

Comment: Your code is working fine in codepen, check [this](https://codepen.io/prinkpan/pen/dBbVxY) just correct the order of javascript includes as given in above comment.

Comment: May I ask why is my code working in bootstrap-datepicker.min.js without errors and not on bootstrap-datepicker.js?

Comment: Ideally, the code should work on both, but you cannot use both `.min.js` and `.js` at the same time.

Comment: If this chat has helped you, please accept the answer so that others looking for similar problems will be able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code that you need to correct.

1. You are using `gijgo.min.js` along with `bootstrap-datepicker.js`.
   These two libraries cannot be used together for `datepicker()`
   because of the conflict. To solve this, remove either one.
2. You are including both `.min.js` and `.js` files of the library which is not needed. You can only include `.min.js` file and remove the other. `.min.js` is just a minified version of original `.js` file.
3. The order of including these libraries in `<script>` tag is important. You should always include dependencies such as jQuery first, followed by bootstrap and then the others which are dependent on these libraries.

Comment: Yes thanks for the help I've already removed the `gijgo.js`.My problem now is the error still occurs on `.js` file. While doesn't occur on `.min.js`. And as I see the one that you've used in codepen is only the `.min.js` version. How come the `.js` and `.min.js` produces different results?

Comment: It should not produce different results. If you want to use `.js` then you have to remove `.min.js` try with https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-datepicker@1.9.0/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js

Comment: I've already remove the `.min.js` because i wanted to use the `.js` instead but I can't understand why it still produces that error? By the way I'm using `bootstrap-datepicker 1.8.0` not 1.9.0 but i think it doesn't matter because its almost the same

Comment: I have edited my [codepen](https://codepen.io/prinkpan/pen/dBbVxY) to include only `.js` and removed `.min.js`. It is working fine.

Comment: May i ask because now I'm using bootstrap 3 only and as I've see your using bootstrap 4 I'm thinking that maybe the bootstrap version is one of the reason why the error occurs?